# How to resolve "release command failed" in quickly app hello-world?

Tags: application-development, quickly

I am new to Ubuntu and new to programming. I watched the video on http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/ and the video made it look so easy. I followed all the steps and everything was going good until i tried to release the app as demonstrated in the video.

I am sure that i am not the only person to get this error. Please tell me how to fix the error.

Here is the error i received.(I have removed my name and e-mail address from the error message.)

```
user@ubuntu:~/hello-world$ quickly release
Get Launchpad Settings
Launchpad connection is ok
...........Ubuntu packaging created in debian/
.........pushing to launchpad
..................
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "user "
2048-bit RSA key, ID F89E77C4, created 2012-04-27

......
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "user "
2048-bit RSA key, ID F89E77C4, created 2012-04-27

......Checking signature on .changes
gpg: Signature made Fri 27 Apr 2012 10:24:56 PM EDT using RSA key ID F89E77C4
gpg: Good signature from "user "
Good signature on ../hello-world_12.04.9_source.changes.
Checking signature on .dsc
gpg: Signature made Fri 27 Apr 2012 10:24:55 PM EDT using RSA key ID F89E77C4
gpg: Good signature from "user "
Good signature on ../hello-world_12.04.9.dsc.
Uploading to ppa (via ftp to ppa.launchpad.net):
Uploading hello-world_12.04.9.dsc: done.
Uploading hello-world_12.04.9.tar.gz: done.
Uploading hello-world_12.04.9_source.changes: done.
Successfully uploaded packages.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/release.py", line 287, in
release_version), changelog)
File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/internal/launchpad_helper.py", line 57, in push_tarball_to_launchpad
release = create_release(project, version)
File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/internal/launchpad_helper.py", line 44, in create_release
date_targeted=release_date)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 573, in call
url, in_representation, http_method, extra_headers=extra_headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 281, in _request
raise error
lazr.restfulclient.errors.Unauthorized: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
Response headers:

-content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 65
content-type: text/plain
date: Sat, 28 Apr 2012 02:25:01 GMT
server: zope.server.http (HTTP)
status: 401
strict-transport-security: max-age=2592000
vary: Accept,Accept-Encoding
via: 1.1 api.launchpad.net
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-lazr-notifications: []
x-powered-by: Zope (www.zope.org), Python (www.python.org)
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Response body:
(, 'newMilestone', 'launchpad.Edit')

ERROR: release command failed
Aborting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run quickly on my system (version 12,94-0ubuntu1) it asks for a Launchpad project name right after I enter the command `quickly release`. I see that your version didn't do that, therefore quickly may try to upload your version to launchpad.net/hello-world (unless you've already configured quickly to use a different launchpad project name).

If the project name is still hello-world it can't upload it because there already is a project with that name, and you aren't part of the group that controls it. That would explain the message: `lazr.restfulclient.errors.Unauthorized: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`. In that situation you should either start over renaming the program with a unique name, or more simply use the `quickly configure lp-project` command to provide the name of your own project on launchpad.

If you had already configured quickly with your own launchpad project name, please be sure that project already exists under your ownership on Launchpad and please edit your question to mention the project name.

Nevertheless a program shouldn't abort with a traceback, so this is still a bug. Please report it with launchpad.